# Spring MVC - Reload same ModelAndView but with new/different data

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Trying to learn the basics of MVC in Spring (I've only ever used Spring to build REST API's) and I'm having trouble understanding how to return new data to the same view, it seems like I have a lot of duplicated code and the HTML page is completely relying on th:if statements...

What is the best way to make a POST request and then load the same ModelAndView with new/updated data? Code below:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ColorController {

  private ColorService colorService;

  @Autowired
  public ColorController(ColorService colorService) {
    this.colorService = colorService;
  }

  //homepage
  @GetMapping("/")
  public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView welcomeMAV) {
    welcomeMAV.setViewName("welcome");
    welcomeMAV.addObject("message", "What is your RGB color?");
    welcomeMAV.addObject("rgbcolor", new RGBColour());
    welcomeMAV.addObject("hexValue", null);
    return welcomeMAV;
  }

  @PostMapping("/color")
  public ModelAndView colorConvert(ModelAndView welcomeMAV, @ModelAttribute RGBColour rgbColour) {
    welcomeMAV.setViewName("welcome");
    welcomeMAV.addObject("message", "What is your RGB color?");
    welcomeMAV.addObject("rgbcolor", new RGBColour());
    welcomeMAV.addObject("hexValue",  colorService.convertRGBToHex(rgbColour));
    return welcomeMAV;
  }
}
```

welcome.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

  <head th:insert="fragments/header.html">
    <!-- insert <head> html here -->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The NavBar</a>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1>Bytes and Bits</h1>
        <h2>
          Convert your colours
        </h2>
        <hr />

        <p th:if="${hexValue == null}" th:text="${message}" th:unless="${message == null}">No message</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <form th:if="${hexValue == null}" action="#" th:action="@{/color}" th:object="${rgbcolor}" method="post">
            <p>Red: <input id="red" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{red}" onchange="getRed()" /></p>
            <p>Green: <input id="green" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{green}" onchange="getGreen()" /></p>
            <p>Blue: <input id="blue" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{blue}" onchange="getBlue()"/></p>
            <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
          </form>
          <p class="hex-color-text" th:if="${hexValue != null}">The hex value is: <span class="hex-color-text" id="hex-color-text" th:if="${hexValue != null}" th:text="${hexValue}"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="color-preview" id="color-preview">
            <p class="color-preview-text" id="color-preview-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="btn btn-primary" th:if="${hexValue != null}" href="/">Reset</a>

    </main>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refresh the page without reloading, you should go for javascript or jquery.

Now in your situation one controller is enough to do the required operation. call the same controller and add some logic in dao layer.

If color is selected you send that to jsp, else return null.

instead of having logic in jsp, you can do it efficiently using all the layers of mvc(controller,service,dao)

Comment: Instead of applying logic in any layer of MVC, call the Service layer for business logic